# Program to check if printer exists

Tags: c++, c, linux

I'm looking for a way to check if a printer exists on a Linux/Unix machine using a C or C++ program. Something like the following windows program:

```
BOOL IsPrinterExist(LPTSTR pPrinterName)
{
    HANDLE hPrinter = NULL;
    if(OpenPrinter(PRINTERNAME,&hPrinter,NULL))
    {
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        hPrinter = NULL;
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I think I can do it using CUPS API, but I need something that will work on every machine without special installations, using the OS API. I know I can also use issue the `lpstat -a` command and read its output, but I'm looking for a way of doing it directly (do what `lpstat -a` does).

Comment: I would guess `lpstat` uses the CUPS API (see `ldd /usr/bin/lpstat`).

Comment: If CUPS is installed, there is `lpstat` around. If CUPS is not installed, you cannot use CUPS API.

Comment: Don't try to use OS API for this, you will end up writing CUPS :)

Comment: "IsPrinterExist"? My eyes are bleeding...

Answer (score 1):

Since CUPS is the de facto standard for printing on GNU/Linux systems, I wouldn't worry too much about "special installations": if CUPS isn't installed, the machine probably wouldn't be able to print anyway.

To see how to use the CUPS API, take a look at `lpstat`'s [source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cups/cups-59/systemv/lpstat.c).

Comment: So I'll use CUPS. Thank you all.

Comment: @gabriel: Mark this as an **accepted answer** if you satisfy with this answer.